# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'animal_signals' referenced before assignment

Tags: cython

I have a some Cython code where if a variable equals a value from a list then values from another list are copied into a testing array.

```
    double [:] signals
    cdef int total_days=signals.shape[0]
    cdef size_t epoch=0
    cdef int total_animals
    cdef int n
    cdef double[:] animal_signals
    
    for animal in range(total_animals):
        individual_animal = uniq_instr[animal]
                    
        for element in range(total_days):
            if list(animal_ids[n]) == individual_animal:
                animal_signals.append(signals[n])
```

I am getting an error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'animal_signals' referenced before assignment

I have thought having the line

```
cdef double[:] animal_signals
```

would have meant the array was assigned.

### Update

As suggested I have also tried declaring the array animal_signals (and removing the append):

```
cdef int total_days=signals.shape[0]
cdef size_t epoch=0
cdef int total_animals
cdef int n
cdef int count=0

    for animal in range(total_animals):
        count=0
        individual_animal = uniq_instr[animal]
            
        for element in range(total_days):
            if list(animal_ids[element]) == individual_animal:
                cdef double[:] animal_signals[count] = signals[n]
                count=count+1
```

however when I compile the code I get the error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...

        for element in range(total_days):
            if list(animal_ids[element]) == individual_animal:
                cdef double[:] animal_signals[count] = signals[n]
                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

project/temps.pyx:288:21: cdef statement not allowed here
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, your line `cdef double[:] animal_signals`
declares `animal_signals` as a variable, but you never assign anything to it before using it (in Python assignement is done with the `=` operator).

In Cython, using the slice (`[:]`) notation when defining a variable is usually done to get the memory view of an other object (see [the reference documentation](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#using-memoryviews)).

For example :

```
some_1d_numpy_array = np.zeros((10,10)).reshape(-1)
cdef double[:] animal_signals = some_1d_numpy_array
```

If you want to create a C array, you have to [allocate the memory](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/memory_allocation.html) for it (here for a size of `number` entries containing `double`) :

```
cdef double *my_array = <double *> malloc(number * sizeof(double))
```

Also, regarding to your original code, note that in both case you won't be able to use the `append` method on this object because it will not be a Python `list`, you will have to access its member by their indexes.

Comment: Many thanks @mgc.  I have tried to declare stock_signals but am getting an error that I'm not allowed to declare the variable where I have.  I have amended my question to include my attempt at implementing your solution.  Could you let me know what I've done wrong please.

Comment: Thanks @mgc read the link in your answer and it all now makes sense!

Comment: @Stacey i was away from the keyboard so I couldn't answer your first comment but i'm glad it helped :)